# Git rebase from one branch to another

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

I have the following case :

```
                          K---L new-feature
                         /
                H---I---J dev-team1
               /
              E---F---G dev-main
             /
A---B---C---D master
```

And I want to move only the *new-feature* (K---L) branch in *dev-main* branch without (H---I---J) form *dev-team1*

```
                H---I---J dev-team1
               /
              E---F---G---K---L dev-main
             /
A---B---C---D master
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`git rebase` has an `--onto` argument that does what you need.

```
git checkout new-feature
git rebase --onto dev-main dev-team1

# Now new-feature has commits K' and L' after G in dev-main.
git checkout dev-main
git merge --ff-only new-feature
```

See the [man page for "git rebase"](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for more details. (I also like to add a `-i` just to double check that I'm moving the commits that I think I am.)

You could also use `git cherry-pick`, especially if the number of commits is small:

```
git checkout dev-main
git cherry-pick K L
```

Comment: Don't forget cherry-pick supports a range of commits as well

Answer (score 1):

You can cherry-pick K and L commits.

```
git checkout dev-main
git cherry-pick K
```

If you have conflicts, fix the them, and do

```
git cherry-pick --continue
git cherry-pick L
```

Fix the conflicts.

You can also use interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i head~5
```

In the opened editor replace H I and J commits lines with

```
pick F
pick G
```

Comment: You can make code blocks in your answers and questions by having a 4-space indent in front of each line of code.